# Pyside qwebenginWidget no open QWebenginProsser

Tags: tr

I tried to open the web like the article below in pyside2, all that can be displayed is that the applicon cannot open the web.
[How to detect button click inside Qwebengine in pyside2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197927/how-to-detect-button-click-inside-qwebengine-in-pyside2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[code run app no process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkW2n.png)

Open the app without opening the web processs engine